# The second for loop in a function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function like below:

```
function launching() {

    let ranges = document.getElementsByClassName('range');
    liczba2 = 0;
    console.log(ranges);

    let czeks = document.getElementsByClassName('check');
    liczba = 0;
    eluwina = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i <= czeks.length; i++) {
        if (czeks[i].checked) {
            liczba ++;
            console.log(liczba);

        }
    }

    for (let n = 0; ranges.length; n++) {
        let val = ranges.getAttribute('value');
        console.log(val);
    }
}
```

The first for loop works fine. However the second one:

```
for (let n = 0; ranges.length; n++) {
        let val = ranges.getAttribute('value');
        console.log(val);
    }
```

Doesn't work at all. Even if there's just console log after first loop, it won't execute. I'll be grateful if anyone could help me. Thanks in advance :).

Comment: What does `console.log(ranges.length)` show?

Comment: `i <= czeks.length` should use `<`.

Comment: The second loop will not do anything if `ranges` is empty. Otherwise it will be an infinite loop.

Comment: I'd be surprised if the first one actually worked fine, since it has an off-by-one error (there is nothing at `czeks[czeks.length]`). but the second one doesn't work because it expects a Boolean expression that eventually evaluates to false. `ranges.length` will never be false. `n < ranges.length` might...

Comment: And `ranges.getAttribute` should be `ranges[n].getAttribute`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second loop should be:

```js
for (let n = 0; n < ranges.length; n++) {
  let val = ranges[n].getAttribute('value');
  console.log(val);
}
```

In your code, if `ranges.length == 0`, the loop will end immediately, since the condition `ranges.length` is falsey. Otherwise it will be cause an infinite loop, because the value of `ranges.length` doesn't change, and a non-zero value is truthy.

However, the loop will stop because `ranges.getAttribute('value')` will get an error. `ranges` is a `NodeList`, not a single element, and it doesn't have a `getAttribute()` method. You need to index it to get the current element in the iteration.

Comment: You made it all clear to me. Thank you very much mr. Barmar :).